# Are there currently any international land border crossings that rely solely on automated gates?

Tags: borders

Wikipedia states that "Most e-gates (automated border control systems) have been deployed in airports in Europe, Australia and Asia." Are there any land border crossings that rely on automated gates in part or entirely?

Comment: I think it is impossible to rely solely on automated gates: there are always special cases, document to sign and stamp, etc.

Comment: It is hard to proof a negative, but I guess there is not yet a border crossing where all traffic is done by automatic gates, there are too many people who do not qualify, even when only citizens can use that crossing.

Comment: Your title asks about border crossings that don't have manual checkpoints, but your question body asks about **land** border crossings that use automated checkpoints (in part or in whole). Can you clarify what you're asking about?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi One could have a policy where such special cases have to use a different border crossing.

Comment: @gerrit: yeah. Not feasible on airports, but on land yes.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Well, even on airports they could be told to use airside transit to another terminal or so.

Answer (score 7):

All Singapore - Malaysia land borders relies on automatic gates for residents and for people leaving the country (Singapore side). Visitors will still have to convince border agents to let them in. And residents have fallback on using the agents, if they want.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. This and the other answer given, Spain / Gibraltar, are both similar unusual situations where one territory is very small and stuck on to the end of the other with no other border, only sea. So the interior territory has the assurance that anyone coming in from the exterior territory got there through an airports/seaport, or by crossing over from the interior in the first place and was thus vetted by the exterior territory.

Answer (score 6):

The Spain/Gibraltar border has a row of automated gates (they can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/mr83gc8q_kA?t=82)) that scan identity documents for those exiting and entering Spain. The Gibraltar authorities have their own checkpoint entering as well.

They do not rely entirely on the automated gates. When I visited, as a non-EU national, they just waved me through the side door around the gates.

Answer (score -1):

Brazil has some automated gates in Guarulhos International Airport and Viracopos International Airport (Campinas).

You can use if you are a Brazilian Resident and you do not have any minor with you.

I am not sure, but the same approach could be used in other places in Brazil.

> Brazil’s Viracopos International Airport, which serves Campinas, São
>   Paulo, has implemented automated border control e-gates, which make
>   use of facial recognition technology to secure the border control
>   process and create a more seamless passenger experience.
>
> The system, which has been implemented by Vision-Box, compares the
>   image stored in the chip of the passenger’s passport to a live
>   captured image. According to the vendor, the e-gates reduce the time
>   taken to clear border control from three minutes to around 15 seconds.
>
> President & Director of Viracopos International Airport, Gustavo
>   Müssnich, said: “After Viracopos reached a record in passenger volume
>   in a single year (10.3m in 2015), this new technology has arrived to
>   make the airport journey much more seamless and secure.”
>
> Leidivino Natal da Silva, General Director of Vision-Box Latin
>   America, explained that the system will help the airport to optimise
>   passenger flow.
>
> “One of the trends of special interest in the aviation industry is
>   currently to refine security processes in order to increase
>   reliability and sustainability,” he explained. “Viracopos
>   International Airport is highly aware and decided to focus on the
>   solution that brings higher levels of innovation and orientation to
>   passenger experience.”

Source: [Future Travel Experience](https://www.futuretravelexperience.com/2016/01/viracopos-airport-implements-automated-border-control/)

Comment: This question is about land borders.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am sorry by my misunderstanding. When I read "land", I imagined this definition: a portion of the earth's solid surface distinguishable by boundaries or ownership. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land). Also, I did not pay attention for the all expression 'land border crossings'. Thx by your help...